# Conversion of sql table to excel table

Tags: c#, sql, export-to-excel

In my application I want database data exported to Excel sheet and I have to make this file as readonly and  I want to display message if the user try to edit the Excel Like-you are not allowed to edit this sheet I'm doing this in console application.

I have written code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace ConsoleApplication1{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
         ("");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        ("select Temprature,time,date from temprature3 ", con);
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        OdbcConnection dcon = new OdbcConnection();
        dcon.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)};Create_DB=C:\Documents andSettings\Administrator\Desktop\Excel\Report.xls;DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Excel\Report.xls;
  ReadOnly=True";
        dcon.Open();
        OdbcCommand dcom=new OdbcCommand
           ("create table Report new
           (Temperature double,Time datetime,Date datetime)",dcon);
        dcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("table has been created");
        OdbcCommand dinsert=new OdbcCommand("insert into Report values(?,?,?)",dcon);
        OdbcParameter Temprature=new OdbcParameter("@Temperature",OdbcType.Double);
        OdbcParameter Time=new OdbcParameter("@Temperature",OdbcType.DateTime);
        OdbcParameter Date=new OdbcParameter("@Temperature",OdbcType.DateTime);
        dinsert.Parameters.Add(Temprature);
        dinsert.Parameters.Add(Time);
        dinsert.Parameters.Add(Date);
        int count=0;
        while(data.Read())
        {
            Temprature.Value=data[0];
            Time.Value=data[1];
            Date.Value=data[2];
            dinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            count=count+1;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(count+"Number of rows are exported to excel");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting error like this:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: your SqlConnection requires a connection string?

Comment: ya i have written in my code but i have not displayed here..

Comment: Could it be the spaces in the file path...? try wrapping with `"`...

Comment: no there is no space inthe filepath..

Comment: Is your excel sheet name correct? Sheet is supposed to be something like [Report$]....

Comment: @prime-i have created excel file and i want the data of database to be copied into it..

Answer (score 0):

My 2 Cents on this :- 
Make sure the data source name was given correctly. If this is correct make sure the driver is installed correctly. Try reinstalling it.

Also make sure the data source name was defined using the same Windows NT account the application is running under.

If the application is running as a Windows NT service, the data source must be a system data source.

Comment: @roy -where should i check whether driver is installed or not if you dont mind can you tell me...

Comment: check registry for this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ODBC\ODBC Drivers